# Whis is the error in angular, I couldnot find it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

here is my code.. where I made problem.. please help me out.. I am trying to create a controller what fill fetch data and show in html li part.. but I don't understand where is the error.. I have tried with adding jQuery min library and without it.. but failure.. kindly help me to short out this problem..

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>First Angular application</title>
</head>
<body>
    checkNames:
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="namek">
    <div class="container" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cast in castomers | filter:namek">{{cast.name|uppercase}} - {{cast.city}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.castomers = [{ name: 'krishnendu sarkar', city: 'kolkata' },
                                { name: 'chanchal sarkar', city: 'bangalore' },
                                { name: 'nilava chakraborty', city: 'pune' }]
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: Kindly explain what *is* your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create and `angular` module first with name `myApp` then you could have `data-ng-controller="SimpleController"` to be move it over `body` tag so that the `namek` input field included inside the `SimpleController` controller context.

Add ng-app="myApp" on the body tag. so that angular module gets initialize on page.

**Markup**

```
<body  data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
  checkNames:
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="namek">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="cast in castomers | filter:namek">{{cast.name|uppercase}} - {{cast.city}}</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);

function SimpleController($scope) {
  $scope.castomers = [{
    name: 'krishnendu sarkar',
    city: 'kolkata'
  }, {
    name: 'chanchal sarkar',
    city: 'bangalore'
  }, {
    name: 'nilava chakraborty',
    city: 'pune'
  }]
};
```

[**Demo PLunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/S49xv8zRlQcfjM5uuScm?p=preview)

Comment: I have found my problem.. 1. you are correct about the module.. another is 2. My angular library is not working properly. After this post I just fetch it from web and it's working properly..

Comment: @KrishnenduSarkar for accepting the answer you need to click on mark arrow beside the up & down arrow..

Comment: @KrishnenduSarkar you had wrong concept about it..that you did is upvote..take a look at this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @KrishnenduSarkar Correct..Thank s

Answer (score 0):

please see this [link here](http://goo.gl/xTyzMh) to see the whole code.

You should create angular module "myApp" which define the application then controller inside it.